# Creating a thin black circle (unfilled) within a filled white circle (UIButton)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, calayer

I'm trying to replicate the default camera button on iOS devices:

[image: https://www.iphonefaq.org/images/archives/photo-tip-shutter1.jpg]

I'm able to create a white circular button with black button within it. However, the black button is also filled, instead of just being a thin circle.

This is what I have (most of it has been copied from different sources and put together, so the code isn't efficient)

The object represents the button,

```
func applyRoundCorner(_ object: AnyObject) {
    //object.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    //object.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
    object.layer.cornerRadius = (object.frame.size.width)/2
    object.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    object.layer.borderWidth = 5
    object.layer.masksToBounds = true
    //object.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    //object.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5

    var CircleLayer   = CAShapeLayer()
    let center = CGPoint (x: object.frame.size.width / 2, y: object.frame.size.height / 2)
    let circleRadius = object.frame.size.width / 6
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
    CircleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    CircleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    //CircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    CircleLayer.lineWidth = 1
    CircleLayer.strokeStart = 0
    CircleLayer.strokeEnd  = 1
    object.layer.addSublayer(CircleLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Basic Approach

You could do it like this (for the purpose of demonstration, I would do the button programmatically, using a playground):

```
let buttonWidth = 100.0

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth))
button.backgroundColor = .white
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.width / 2
```

**Drawing Part:**

So, after adding the button and do the desired setup (make it circular), here is part of how you could draw a circle in it:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: buttonWidth / 2,y: buttonWidth / 2), radius: 40.0, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)

let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
circleLayer.lineWidth = 2.5

// adding the layer into the button:
button.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
```

<sub>Probably, `circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor` is the part you missing .</sub>

Therefore:

[image]

---

### Back to your case:

**Aside Bar Tip:**

For implementing `applyRoundCorner`, I would suggest to let it has *only* the job for rounding the view, and then create another function to add the circle inside the view. And that's for avoiding any naming conflict, which means that when reading "applyRoundCorner" I would *not* assume that it is also would add circle to my view! So:

```
func applyRoundedCorners(for view: UIView) {
    view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width / 2
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

func drawCircle(in view: UIView) {
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2,y: view.frame.size.width / 2),
                                             radius: view.frame.size.width / 2.5,
                                             startAngle: 0,
                                             endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2,
                                             clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.5

    button.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

and now:

```
applyRoundedCorners(for: button)
drawCircle(in: button)
```

That's seems to be better. From another aspect, consider that you want to make a view to be circular *without* add a circle in it, with separated methods you could simply `applyRoundedCorners(for: myView)` without the necessary of adding a circle in it.

---

#### Furthermore:

As you can see, I changed `AnyObject` to `UIView`, it seems to be more logical to your case. So here is a cool thing that we could do:

```
extension UIView {
    func applyRoundedCorners(for view: UIView) {
        view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width / 2
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    func drawCircle(in view: UIView) {
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2,y: view.frame.size.width / 2),
                                      radius: view.frame.size.width / 2.5,
                                      startAngle: 0,
                                      endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2,
                                      clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.5

        button.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Now both `applyRoundedCorners` and `drawCircle` are implicitly included to the `UIView` (which means `UIButton`), instead of passing the `button` to these functions, you would be able to:

```
button.applyRoundedCorners()
button.drawCircle()
```

Comment: Correction: 'self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)' instead of 'button.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)'

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add circle Shape layer with lesser width and height

Try this code

```
func applyRoundCorner(_ object: UIButton) {
    object.layer.cornerRadius = (object.frame.size.width)/2
    object.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    object.layer.borderWidth = 5
    object.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let anotherFrame = CGRect(x: 12, y: 12, width: object.bounds.width - 24, height: object.bounds.height - 24)
    let circle = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: object.center, radius: anotherFrame.width / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)
    circle.path = path.cgPath
    circle.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    circle.lineWidth = 1.0
    circle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    object.layer.addSublayer(circle)
}
```

Note: Change frame value according to your requirements and best user experience

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have no doubt there are a million different ways to approach this problem, this is just one...

I started with a `UIButton` for simplicity and speed, I might consider actually starting with a `UIImage` and simply setting the image properties of the button, but it would depend a lot on what I'm trying to achieve

```
internal extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

class RoundButton: UIButton {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        makeButtonImage()?.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    }

    func makeButtonImage() -> UIImage? {
        let size = bounds.size

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height))
        defer {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }

        let center = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2.0, y: size.height / 2.0)
        // Want to "over fill" the image area, so the mask can be applied
        // to the entire image
        let radius = min(size.width / 2.0, size.height / 2.0)

        let innerRadius = radius * 0.75
        let innerCircle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                                                     radius: innerRadius,
                                                                     startAngle: CGFloat(0.0).degreesToRadians,
                                                                     endAngle: CGFloat(360.0).degreesToRadians,
                                                                     clockwise: true)
        // The color doesn't matter, only it's alpha level
        UIColor.red.setStroke()
        innerCircle.lineWidth = 4.0
        innerCircle.stroke(with: .normal, alpha: 1.0)

        let circle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                                            radius: radius,
                                                            startAngle: CGFloat(0.0).degreesToRadians,
                                                            endAngle: CGFloat(360.0).degreesToRadians,
                                                            clockwise: true)
        UIColor.clear.setFill()
        ctx.fill(bounds)

        UIColor.white.setFill()
        circle.fill(with: .sourceOut, alpha: 1.0)

        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

*nb: This is **unoptimised**! I would consider caching the result of `makeButtonImage` and invalidate it when the state/size of the button changes, just beware of that*

Why is this approach any "better" then any other? I just want to say, it's not, but what it does create, is a "cut out" of the inner circle

[image: Playground Result]

It's a nitpick on my part, but I think it looks WAY better and is a more flexible solution, as you don't "need" a inner circle stroke color, blah, blah, blah

The solution makes use of the [CoreGraphics `CGBlendMode`s](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgblendmode)

Of course I might just do the whole thing in [PaintCodeApp](https://www.paintcodeapp.com) and be done with it